# How can we extract date only from a column with various date and string formats in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql

| **ACTUAL** | **expected** |
| --- | --- |
| SEP-10-2017 | 10-SEP-2017 |
| SEP 30 2018 | 30-SEP-2018 |
| OFFICE OF SMALL |  |
| OCT-11-2018 | 11-OCT-2018 |
| O9-SEP-2009 | O9-SEP-2009 |
| Not Applicable |  |
| NOV-20-2001 | 20-NOV-2001 |
| BANIJYA BHIBAG |  |
| AUGUST 03 2017 | 03-AUG-2017 |
| AUG-04-1991 | 04-AUG-1991 |
| 97/2015 |  |
| 09/09/2018 | 09-SEP-2018 |

how can we get the result as above and discard the date that cannot be converted?

Comment: Hi Nepal, check out this answer on "ask Tom" https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=date-validation-without-function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Oracle 12, you do not need PL/SQL and can use:

```sql
SELECT actual,
       COALESCE(
         TO_DATE(
           actual DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR,
           'MM-DD-YYYY',
           'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH'
         ),
         TO_DATE(
           actual DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR,
           'DD-MON-YYYY',
           'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH'
         )
       ) AS parsed
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (ACTUAL) AS
SELECT 'SEP-10-2017'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SEP 30 2018'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'OFFICE OF SMALL' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'OCT-11-2018'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'O9-SEP-2009'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Not Applicable'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'NOV-20-2001'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'BANIJYA BHIBAG'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AUGUST 03 2017'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AUG-04-1991'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '97/2015'         FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '09/09/2018'      FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ACTUAL | PARSED |
> | --- | --- |
> | SEP-10-2017 | 10-SEP-2017 |
> | SEP 30 2018 | 30-SEP-2018 |
> | OFFICE OF SMALL |  |
> | OCT-11-2018 | 11-OCT-2018 |
> | O9-SEP-2009 |  |
> | Not Applicable |  |
> | NOV-20-2001 | 20-NOV-2001 |
> | BANIJYA BHIBAG |  |
> | AUGUST 03 2017 | 03-AUG-2017 |
> | AUG-04-1991 | 04-AUG-1991 |
> | 97/2015 |  |
> | 09/09/2018 | 09-SEP-2018 |

*Note: `O9-SEP-2009` has not parsed because you have the letter `O` rather than the digit `0` as the first character.*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c748d9a3a4189d8747e36853bf52ac41)*

Comment: @MTO very nicely done

Comment: @MT0 , works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a function which will cover **all** possible combinations. The following example has some of them - you'd have to add new when you find them.

```
SQL> create or replace function f_date (par_str in varchar2)
  2    return date
  3  is
  4    l_date date;
  5  begin
  6    begin
  7      l_date := to_date(par_str, 'mon-dd-yyyy');
  8      return l_date;
  9    exception
 10      when others then null;
 11    end;
 12
 13    --
 14
 15    begin
 16      l_date := to_date(par_str, 'mon dd yyyy');
 17      return l_date;
 18    exception
 19      when others then null;
 20    end;
 21
 22    --
 23
 24    begin
 25      l_date := to_date(par_str, 'dd-mon-yyyy');
 26      return l_date;
 27    exception
 28      when others then null;
 29    end;
 30
 31    --
 32
 33    begin
 34      l_date := to_date(par_str, 'month dd yyyy');
 35      return l_date;
 36    exception
 37      when others then null;
 38    end;
 39
 40    --
 41
 42    begin
 43      l_date := to_date(par_str, 'dd/mm/yyyy');
 44      return l_date;
 45    exception
 46      when others then null;
 47    end;
 48
 49    return null;
 50
 51  exception
 52    when others then
 53      return null;
 54  end f_date;
 55  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select actual, f_date(actual) as expected
  2  from test;

ACTUAL          EXPECTED
--------------- -----------
SEP-10-2017     10-SEP-2017
SEP 30 2018     30-SEP-2018
OFFICE OF SMALL
09-SEP-2009     09-SEP-2009
Not applicable
AUGUST 03 2017  03-AUG-2017
97/2015
09/09/2018      09-SEP-2018

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```

---

Possible problems: if `actual = 09/10/12`, what is what?

- 09 can be day, month or year
- 10 can also be day, month or year
- 12 can also be day, month or year

So, what is it?

- 09-OCT-2012
- 10-SEP-2012
- 12-OCT-2009
- ...

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure about that you don't have any other type of the format for those values which can be convertible to a date value(eg.all of the data conform with this sample data set), then use the following code block in order to populate another table(`t2`) with the decent date values while displaying the rotten values such as

```sql
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL> DECLARE
  dt DATE;
BEGIN
  FOR c IN (SELECT * FROM t) LOOP
    BEGIN
      dt := TO_DATE(c.col, 'MON-DD-YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH');
      INSERT INTO t2 VALUES(c.id,c.col);
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        BEGIN
          dt := TO_DATE(c.col, 'DD/MM/YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH');
          INSERT INTO t2 VALUES(c.id,c.col);
        EXCEPTION
          WHEN OTHERS THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(c.col || ' is not a valid date value');          
        END;
    END;
  END LOOP;
  COMMIT;
END;
/
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=90e75c23e6fbaab6a86c6e42eac956e1)</kbd>